# How to set jsfiddle's javascript version?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I wanted to use javascript's `yield` keyword (similar to C#'s `yield return`) in jsFiddle. I know that  `yield` works on Firefox only, I want to make a one-off simulation, so it doesn't have to be cross-platform. Is it possible to set jsFiddle's javascript to version 1.7?

Comment: Yep - in the tab called `panels` on the left hand side - use the Javascript drop down - this should be on META.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Neurofluxation just put your comment in answer. I'll upvote and accept it

Comment: @Neurofluxation I upvoted it now. can only accept after 11 minutes, i'll accept it later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep - in the tab called `Languages`on the left hand side - you can change the `JavaScript` drop down to `Javascript 1.7` - this should be on META.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle runs JavaScript in the browser. Consequently, it uses whatever version of JS your browser is running.

jsFiddle does not have an inherent "JavaScript version."

Comment: it has an inherent version, if you wanted to use `yield` functionality in javascript (which is present in version javascript 1.7 only. for now, firefox is the only browser that supported it), you must explicitly set the javascript version to 1.7

Comment: @Hao of course, so that jsFiddle will use `<script>` tag, with `type="application/javascript;version=1.7"` so that FF picks it up. Now I see what you needed.